# Insert event in google calendar using service account with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I can't insert an event using Nodejs with service account.
The service account Email is already added into the account with the permission make changes to event
My nodejs code is running on google cloud functions
Here is my code:

```js
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');


var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2020-02-10T13:00:00-05:00'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2020-02-10T15:00:00-05:00'
  },
  'attendees': [{
    'email': 'Emailh@domain.com'
  }],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [{
        'method': 'email',
        'minutes': 24 * 60
      },
      {
        'method': 'popup',
        'minutes': 10
      },
    ],
  },
};

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  }).then(auth => {
    const calendar = google.calendar({
      version: 'v3',
      auth
    });
    calendar.events.insert({
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: 'MyCalendarID',
      resources: event,
    }, function(err, event) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
    });
  })

};
```

the same code works fine when I use the function read.
Any Idea ?

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events` `read/write access to Events` (https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)

Comment: I tried it, it did not change anything, according to this documentations, https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert we can put https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Comment: There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Missing end time.

Comment: I have added this in my functions: res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type:application/json, Accept');

Comment: Maybe try `npm uninstall googleapis` then `npm install googleapis@latest --save`.

Comment: Well the good news I had resources instead of resource, I corrected that, now I have another error: There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes specified. Calendar usage limits exceeded.

Comment: I tried both scope: calendar and calendar.events, same issue !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a known bug**

There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141704931) when adding attendees to an event with a Service Account.

The current workaround is to **impersonate** a user using [G Suite Domain-wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority). If you do so, you should be able to create the events with attendees.

Another option is to remove the attendees from the Event creation request.

Comment: you'r the best, I have removed the attendees, and it works! but still I t without the attenddees, it's not sexy. Google should work on that.

Comment: Anyone who sees this, I recommend you star the issue to encourage Google to fix it sooner!