# Google Calendar API: 403 Calendar Usage Limits Exceeded

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I built an app using Python and its connected to the google calendar API.

I don't understand why I get this error "Google Calendar API: 403 Calendar Usage Limits Exceeded Using Service Account"

I barely added events, maybe 300 in a week.

I used to have an old account and I added thousands in days. Now, with this new, free account, It gave me this error!

What can I do? Is it fixable?!

**Initiate Calendar Service :**

```
def initiate_calendar_service():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
        Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
        """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    return service
```

**ADD EVENT:**

```
        for i in range(1):

            startStrip = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            endStrip = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            dayOfWeek = startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
            # les bons formats
            currentStart = str(startStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")
            currentEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).replace(" ", "T")
            calendarEnd = str(endStrip + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).replace(" ", "T")


            events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=currentStart + "-00:00",
                                                  maxResults=30, timeMax=calendarEnd + "-00:00",
                                                  singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
            events = events_result.get('items', [])

            currentEmployees = []
            for event in events:
                currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])

            if employee in currentEmployees:
                event_done = False
                event['summary'] = employee
                
                for event in events:
                   if str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                    event_done = False
                    print(employee + ' est occupé')
                    break
                   else:
                      event_done = True
                      break

            if employee not in currentEmployees:
                event_done = True

            if event_done:
                option = show_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                                      "Confirmation",
                                      "Voulez-vous bloquer cette plage horraire?"\
                                      "L'employé : \"" + employee + "\" sera marqué comme indisponible en raison de : " + reason, \
                                      "Nom de l'employé: " + employee + "\n" \
                                      "Raison: " + reason + "\n" \
                                      "À partir du : " + currentStart + "\n" \
                                      "À ce jour " + currentEnd + "\n"
                                      )

                if option == QMessageBox.Yes:
                    event_done = True
                else:
                    print("Événement ignoré!")
                    event_done = False
                    break

                if event_done:
                    event = {
                        'summary': employee,
                        'location': location,
                        'description': reason,
                        'start': {
                            'dateTime': currentStart,
                            'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
                        },
                        'end': {
                            'dateTime': currentEnd,
                            'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
                        },
                        'attendees': [
                            {'email': event_email},
                        ],
                        'reminders': {
                            'useDefault': True,
                        },
                    }
                    register_event(service, event)

            else:
                second_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                                      "ATTENTION!",
                                      "L'inspecteur " + employee + " est déjà occupé à ce moment-là.""\n" \
                                      "Veuillez essayer une autre plage horraire.", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

**Additional information:**

I had one account, and in 1 month, I did 3041 calendar.events.list requests. and 181 calendar.events.insert.

I had NO problem.

This time, with a new account, in 2 days, I did 730 calendar.events.list requests, and 175 calendar.events.insert. Is 175 event insert is a lot in 2 days??

Comment: How many attendees are there per event?  This also effects things.

Comment: only 1 @DaImTo !! also, maxResults was set to 300 by mistake. Even if I didnt had that many. I have max 10 events per day in my calendar. Do you think it's the issue? Am I gonna have this message forever? lol

Comment: Max rows shouldn't effect this

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: my code is 200+ lines... @DaImTo

Comment: Lets just start with the authorization.  How are you creating service and authenticating it.

Comment: I would bug report this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B)  Put the Oauth code in and the error message.   Your using installed application credentials yet getting an error about service accounts.   Then wait to see if someone with more Python knowlage then me could see any issues on yourside.

Comment: in credentials, I see :

No OAuth clients to display

No service accounts to display. 

this is what I see in the credentials tab.. I have a google maps API key only. @DaImTo

Comment: @DaImTo is it normal that I have no OAuth 2.0 Client IDs ?

Comment: The way I connected my app to google calendar is via this website : https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js   I downloaded the credentials.json , stuff it into my project directory, ran it, signed in, it created the pickle file, and that's it. @DaImTo

Comment: you do your looking at the rong project

Comment: you're righ @DaImTo Wrong project. Now for some odd reason, I can add event again... but i'm scared cause it can stop at any time. I have no clue how to play this now..

Comment: I still think you should consider repporting it as a bug.

Comment: @DaImTo when i click "report the issue", I need to enter component and title, what are these? Theyre blank, and IF i write something, the "create" button stays greyed out. I Cannot click 'create'. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: Public Trackers > G Suite Developers > Calendar  <--- component

Comment: 403 Calendar Usage Limits Exceeded Using Service Account using installed credentials  <-- title

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141138/insert-event-in-google-calendar-using-service-account-with-nodejs/60150082#60150082) answer your question? It's a known bug, removing the attendees fixes the issue.

Comment: @Jescanellas What is a service account? I Dont have one. I have a normal gmail account that I created in a minute and connected it to my app via the credential file.

Comment: According to your error message, you are using a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#what_are_service_accounts). They are free for anyone with a Google account, so it's probable your credentials file is from one of those, instead of the credentials from a regular Gmail account.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python this is where I got my credentials file ... @Jescanellas

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I was authorized to Google Calendar API as for example myuser@gmail.com and then I was trying to add the same user (myuser@gmail.com) as an attendee.

When I was adding any other attendees than myuser@gmail.com it worked.

This may explain why sometimes you get the error and sometimes not.

Comment: Additionally, I observed that the quotas related to the number of invitation sent are much more strict for my account than the documentation claims. Even if I use paid Google Workspace account. After sending about 20 invitations to the same user I was unable to add the user email to attendees anymore for about 24 hours.